# Calendar in linux shell programming problems

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, cat

I want my calendar to correctly handle months with leading zeros 
for example:  "cal 01" or "cal 01 2012"

How do I write the code to make my calendar to correctly handle months with leading zeros?

This is my code so far:

```
$ cat cal
#cal: nicer interface to /usr/bin/cal

case $# in
0)  set 'data';m=$2; y=$6 ;;    # no argu: use today
1)  m=$1; set 'data'; y=$6 ;;   # 1 rg: use this year
*)  m=$1; y=$2 ;;           # 2 ags: month and year 
esac

case $m in
jan*|Jan*)  m=1 ;;
feb*|Feb*)  m=2 ;;
mar*|Mar*)  m=3 ;;
apr*|Apr*)  m=4 ;;
may*|May*)  m=5 ;;
jun*|Jun*)  m=6 ;;
jul*|Jul*)  m=7 ;;
aug*|Aug*)  m=8 ;;
sep*|Sep*)  m=9 ;;
oct*|Oct*)  m=10 ;;
nov*|Nov*)  m=11 ;;
dec*|Dec*)  m=12 ;;
[1-9]|10|11|12) ;;          # numeric month
*)      y=$m; m="" ;;       # plain year
esac

/usr/bin/cal $m $y          # run the real one
$
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? I don't see one being asked.

Comment: Please edit your post to add the question or provide more information, instead of writing comments. Thanks.

Comment: alright i put it in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do multiple regex matching in your case statement, i.e.

```
case $m in
01|1|jan*|Jan*)  m=1 ;;
02|2|feb*|Feb*)  m=2 ;;

....
```

Else, you could use shell parameter substitution to remove any leading 0's, i.e.

```
# as a way to demonstrate param sub on $1 etc, load values to $1 and $2
set -- 01 02 
echo ${1#0}
echo ${2#0}

# output
1
2
```

**Edit**

For your follow-up question

> Example, the current month is November, 2005, if you run "cal 01", you should print out the calendar of Jan. 2006

Try this:

```
# if the month input is less than the current month, assume the next year
if (( ${y:-0} == 0  && m < $(/bin/date +%m) )) ; then
   y=$(/bin/date +%Y)
   ((y++))
fi
```

`${y:-0}` is one of several parameter checking syntaxs provided by most shells that allows a default value to be substituted if the var value is completely unset (not set at all) or = "". So in this case, if `y` wasn't set by the command line, it will appear as 0 in this evaluation, allowing  the `&&` section to be be executed to test the month, etc.

You'll need to extend your `case $#` processing to allow for 1 argument, that is assumed to be a month value.

I hope this helps.

Comment: how could i check to see if the month passed is the current year and if it is then make it print out that month in the next year.Example, the current month is November, 2005, if you run "cal 01", you should print out the calendar of Jan. 2006.

Comment: so if the month value is less than the current month, assume the next year? I have to go out now, but will edit later, if this is what you want. Thanks for the check-mark!

Comment: @user977154 : check out the additional info I have added, per your request. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i was looking for, thank you so much for the help.

Comment: I know you have already answered a ton of my questions but i was wondering how can i change my input year and month? so i can test me other test cases.

Comment: I don't understand. isn't that $1 and $2 are for?

Comment: ya so would i just set those equal to a number in the code. Because my codes output is just todays calender

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5486/discussion-between-shellter-and-user977154)